# How do I save an XML node's content to a string?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have and XML like this:

```
<album>
  <image size="small">http://exaplem/example.jpg</image>
  <image size="medium">http://exaplem/example.jpg</image>
  <image size="large"> http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/42566323.png </image>
  <image size="extralarge"> http://exaplem/example.jpg </image>
</album>
```

...and I want to extract and save `<image size="large">...</image>` as string.

My goal is obtaining the child text node of the extracted element. For example `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/42566323.png`.

I've tried with

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("image[@size='large']");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    .....
}
```

... but I'm lost.

What's the best way to do what I require to do?

Comment: i edit it sorry, first post. i try with XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("image[@size='large']");

Comment: No prob. If you want help from the community you'll have to show that at least you tried to do something, people here will help you but they won't do the work for you.

Comment: Try `xml.SelectNodes("//image[@size='large']");`

Comment: Ok, now i get the correct data, thank you

Comment: this looks similar to what you're trying to achieve: [How do I write an XML string to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590881/how-do-i-write-an-xml-string-to-a-file)

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez I've edited your question's text. Please check how I changed your original question. Put some "love" when you ask a question, avoid "chat language".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use LINQ 2 XML:

Assuming you have following xml document:

```
</album>
  <image size="small">http://exaplem/example.jpg</image>
  <image size="medium">http://exaplem/example.jpg</image>
  <image size="large"> http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/42566323.png </image>
  <image size="extralarge"> http://exaplem/example.jpg </image>
</album>
```

Try something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourDocumentString);
var largeImageUrl = doc.Root.Elements("image").Single(image => image.Attribute("size").Value == "large").Value;
```

Comment: But isn't xpath more simple? `var url = doc.XPathSelectElement("//image[@size='large']").Value`

Comment: @L.B I'd vote for XDocument rather than XPath as .NET XPath implementation isn't on top of 2.0 specification and Linq2Xml is more feature rich by far.

Comment: `XPathSelectElement` is an extension method for `XDocument` and `XElement`. still Linq2Xml.

Comment: @L.B. Maybe it's simplier, I've never used it ;) Enjoy!

Comment: @L.B Yes, but I suspect that's a shortcut to regular XPath implementation. Correct me if I'm wrong with that (I'll be happy to know it).

Comment: @L.B Thanks for sharing info about "XPathSelectElement"!

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez Sorry, I've edited answer. ".Value" is not method - it's property.