# Want to find a specific node in xml

Tags: c#, xml

Currently, I have the xml as the following:

```
<Node_Parent>

 <Column name="ColA" value="A" />
 <Column name="ColB" value="B" />
 <Column name="ColC" value="C" />
</Node_Parent>
```

How to get value B at ColB? I tried to use `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("Node_Parent")`, but I cannot access to ColB?

If I change to  `<ColB value="B" />`, I can use `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("Node_Parent/ColB").Attributes["value"].Value`, but the xml format doesn't look good?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't look good"? Also, are you able to use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument? It's certainly possible to do what you want with XmlDocument and XPath, but I'd personally use LINQ to XML.

Comment: Look for similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700375/how-do-i-save-an-xml-nodes-content-to-a-string/13700556

Comment: Did you try an xpath such as /Node_Parent/Column[@Name = 'ColB']/@value ?

Comment: Is it the actual XML? IF not, beware of the possible namespace in the xml. This will have to be specified if nodes are in a namespace

Comment: hi all, I'm very appriciated for you help. Finally, I've got the result, it save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an XPath query in the `SelectSingleNode`:

```
var value = doc.SelectSingleNode(
    "Node_Parent/Column[@name = 'ColB']"
    ).Attributes["value"].Value;
```

For more info on the XPath query language, see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath.

Good luck!