# How to move UI controls in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm planning to create a desktop application That has moveable UI. How can attain it and save the specific settings of user? Within a local computer.

Comment: Write it to a file or settings within the project. Have you done any research of how to save data? You could just save the `.Location` property

Comment: You can use mouse events to create moveable UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Canvas and add your controls to that. With adorners you can make the controls dragable.

On UIElement moved or on shutdown you save the positions e.g. to a xml file like described here:

[How do I write an XML string to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590881/how-do-i-write-an-xml-string-to-a-file)

An example for an adorner:

https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/