# How to I write the contents of XML file(XmlDocument) to text file?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I've  xml data inside a local variable `xml` of type `XMLDocument`
I wish to save the xml data as it is into a local file.

I've tried something like `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MyProfile\OutOut.txt", xml.ToString());` but doesn't work.

Can someone let me know how to proceed for this?

Also let me now if any additional data is needed.

Thanks.

**Update: ** The above task was accomplished by using `XmlDocument.Save(FilePath);` now just a small update to the questio is like :

If I have to save only a specific parent node along with it's child nodes, how do I proceed

Sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Master Name="Accounts">
<Employee>
    <Section>
      <Details>
        <Name="abc" ID="68" PF="9999" />
      </Details>
      <Department DeptId="12" />
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Details>
        <Name="xyz" ID="69" PF="9999"  />
      </Details>
      <Department DeptId="13" />
    </Section>
</Employee>
</Master>
```

Only Node `<Employee>` and it's children.

Comment: Have you looked to see if perhaps the [`XmlDocument` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) provides a method that meets your needs?

Comment: Or search the internet for something like *xmldocument to string c#*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write an XML string to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590881/how-do-i-write-an-xml-string-to-a-file)

Comment: XmlDocument.Save() - Use the File name as "<FileName>.txt"

Comment: The ToString method is the correct solution.  Why doesn't it work.  I suspect there are no carriage returns so every thing is on one line.  Xml doesn't require the return so what you have is correct.

Comment: @BACON Thanks for highlighting. Got this `XmlDocument.Save("FileName");` and it works but I was just wondering if there's a way to save data from a specific parent node including all it's child node.
I saw this `XMLDocument.SelectNodes()` but I'm not getting the `xpath` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts XmlDocument to text:

```
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Comment: As much code as there is here it doesn't accomplish the stated goal of saving to a file.

Comment: Saving the Xml content into a text file was accomplished using `XmlDocument.Save(FilePath);` .